# Not getting json data response in browser is "Cannot GET /api/details"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, server

I am trying to create endpoints in express

```
filename:server.js


var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var userData = [{id:1, firstname:"Avi", lastname:"something", emailid:"abc.xyz@gmail.com"},{id:2, firstname:"Axi", lastname:"anything", emailid:"def.ghi@gmail.com"}];

app.get('/api/details', function(req, res) {
  res.json(JSON.stringify(userData));
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Magic Happening at Port ",port);
});
```

in browser I am entering "127.0.0.1:3000/api/details"

but I am getting 404 error. I am not uderstanding why is it not working?

Thank You for help

Comment: Your code seems fine, and it works for me. Can you try accessing `localhost:3000/api/details` instead? Does that work?

Comment: No it is not working. but what is difference between (127.0.0.1:3000/api/details) and (localhost:3000/api/details)

Comment: I don't know what happened but when I restarted server two times. It started  to work correctly.

Comment: @AviatorX every time you change the code you have to restart the server for the changes to be reflected.